# JSON deserialization C++

Tags: c++, json, serialization

I want to deserialize JSON file to an object(class) using C++. I've looked at rapidjson library and I made each class have a deserialize method with the root as parameter, so it can deserialize itself. It looks like this:

```
void PoliceOfficer::Deserialize(rapidjson::Value& root)
{
if (root.IsObject())
{
    if (root.HasMember("name"))
    {
        if (root["name"].IsString())
        {
            name = root["name"].GetString();
        }
    }

    if (root.HasMember("maxHealth"))
    {
        if (root["maxHealth"].IsNumber())
        {
            maxHealth = (float)root["maxHealth"].GetDouble();
        }
    }

    if (root.HasMember("skills"))
    {
        rapidjson::Value& skills = root["skills"];
        if (skills.IsArray())
        {
            for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < skills.Size(); i++)
            {
                Skill tempSkill;

                tempSkill.Deserialize(skills[i]);

                m_skills.push_back(tempSkill);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But this seems like a lot of work. You'd have to implement this method in all the classes you want to deserialize themselves. So I was wondering if there's any way to do this automatically, something like the following line of code(JSON.NET):

```
 Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);
```

so I don't have to write deserialize method for all the classes. Is the way I'm doing it the only way to do it? I'm using rapidjson, but I'm open for trying another library.

I hope the question makes sense :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: C++ doesn't have introspection, so you can't directly do that, but you may look at [boost hana](http://ldionne.com/hana/index.html#tutorial-introspection-json).

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not building it into your class. That makes your classes messy and your code spaghetti. Instead, use free functions.   Also your code is very verbose ; refactor it so that it's just one line per member you're reading.

Comment: @Jarod42 and LightnessRacesinOrbit  (can't add more than one "@user" per comment)  Yeah I was expecting that :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I totally agree with you. This is just a prototype code, I was learning rapidjson

Comment: Maybe 3 years later, but for some who will came here gonna be useful, http://matus-chochlik.github.io/mirror/doc/html/refltool/example/from_rapidjson.html

Comment: @M.M you mean separate the json reading part from the class building? how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

To deal with a problem like the you are having a possible solution concentrate all infos in a single function where you make the mapping structure fields <---> entries in the json/xml/ini file. Something like this:

```
struct abc_t
{
    int a ;
    string b ;
} ;

void serialize(serializer_t &serializer, abc_t &abc)
{
    serializer.exx(abc.a, "abc") ;
    serializer.exx(abc.b, "b") ;
}
```

The problem is how to write this serializer. The solution can be an abstract class like this:

```
class serializer_t
{
public:
    virtual ~serializer_t(void) {}
    virtual void exx(int &value, const char *tag) = 0 ;
    virtual void exx(string &value, const char *tag) = 0 ;
} ;
```

then you will have two derived classes, a serializer_writer_t that implements the writing and a serializer_reader_t implementing the reading.

Another possibility is a static polymorphism: this means making the original `void serialize(serializer_t &serializer, abc_t &abc)` a template function. If you have a composite object then you need to apply this strategy to each sub-object.

Give a look at  [boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html): you will find a deep discussion about all the trade offs involved in this task

Comment: Great solution you got there! Thanks! But it seems like there's no solution that doesn't require any significant amount of work in C++. Therefore I think I'm going to switch to C# for this case, since it's a lot easier and requires less code.

Comment: @user3071028 If you have that degree of freedom then it's the best choice.